# How can I select the first elements in a set of groups?

Tags: xpath

Consider an Xml document that contains an element `<A>`. This element contains several elements all named `<B>`. Each of these elements contains a number of elements.

I want to get a node set, containing the first element in every `<B>` element, in order of appearance.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider this XPath :

```
//B/*[1]
```

The first bit of the XPath (`//B`) looks for all `<B>` elements. Then from each `<B>` element, the next bit (`/*[1]`) will return the first child element.

Sample XML (OP should've been the one who posted an example though, to make his question clearer) :

```
<A>
    <B>
        <foo/>
        <bar/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <foo/>
        <bar/>
    </B>
    <B>
        <foo/>
        <bar/>
    </B>
</A>
```

And the output of above XPath in an online xpath tester by [freeformatter](http://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html#ad-output) :

```
Element='<foo />'
Element='<foo />'
Element='<foo />'
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <a>
    <b><c id="1" /></b>
    <b><c id="2" /></b>
  </a>
  <a>
  <b><c id="3" /></b>
  <b><c id="4" /></b>
  <b><c id="5"/></b>
  <b>
    <c id="6" />
    <c id="7" />
  </b>
</a>
<a>
  <f><c id="3" /></f>
  <b><d id="4" /></b>
</a>
```

With XPath of

> root/a/b[position() = 1]

Resulting in:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <b>
   <c id="1"/>
  </b>
  <b>
   <c id="3"/>
  </b>
  <b>
    <d id="4"/>
  </b>
</root>
```

Comment: That's not the result of this XPath expression. The expression you show only returns `b` element nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Given an example input XML

```
<root>
  <A>
    <B>B 1 1</B>
    <B>B 1 2</B>
  </A>
  <A>
    <B>B 2 1</B>
    <B>B 2 2</B>
  </A>
</root>
```

the following XPath

```
//A//B[1]/text()
```

has the result

```
B 1 1
B 2 1
```

as every first `B` that is a child element of `A` is selected.

Using `//A//B[1]` will result in the complete `B` nodes:

```
<B>B 1 1</B>
<B>B 2 1</B>
```